how to modify animation property in css with angular
I have a simple component like this:
<div id="countdown">
  <div id="countdown-number">{{ countDown }}</div>
  <svg>
    <circle #circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

This is a circle countdown with a number in it. I have also some css, where I animate the countdown:
svg circle {
  ... 
  animation: countdown 5s linear forwards;
}

It works. Now, I want to make the 5s variable in that way, that it is coming from the component.
For this I tried different approaches:

Define a property in css and modify it, f. e.:
this.renderer2.setProperty(
this.circle.nativeElement,
'--time',
${this.time}s
);


The initial time is showed in the component and it gets decremented, but the animation doesn't start.

I set the style on the element, f. e.:
this.renderer2.setStyle(
this.circle.nativeElement,
'animation',
countdown ${this.time}s linear forwards
);


No luck.
The 3. option would be, that I define a simple class, which contains only the animation style, f. e.:
.start-animation {
  animation: countdown 5s linear forwards;
}

And I add this to the element, f. e.:
this.renderer2.addClass(this.circle.nativeElement, 'start-animation');

This starts the animation, but the 5s are hardcoded.
So, the question is, how to solve this issue? How can I define the animation duration dinamically?

I found a simpler solution. I add a variable (as above stated):
animation: countdown var(--time) linear forwards;

Then in the template:
<svg>
    <circle
      #circle
      r="18"
      cx="20"
      cy="20"
      style="--time: {{ time + 's' }}"
    ></circle>
  </svg>


Different solution using state, seems like a better approach!
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  animate,
  keyframes,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';

const stylesArr = [
  style({ transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0 }),
  animate(
    '{{countDown}}s',
    keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0 }),
      style({ transform: 'scale(0.5)', offset: 1 }),
    ])
  ),
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgStyle, FormsModule],
  animations: [
    trigger('animate', [
      state('neutral', style({ transform: 'scale(1)' })),
      state('executed', style({ transform: 'scale(0.5)' })),
      transition(
        'executed => neutral',
        animate(
          '{{countDown}}s',
          keyframes([
            style({ transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0 }),
            style({ transform: 'scale(0.5)', offset: 1 }),
          ])
        )
      ),
    ]),
  ],
  template: `
    <div id="countdown">
      <div id="countdown-number">{{ countDown }}</div>
      <svg>
        <circle #circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20" class="needed-styles" [@animate]="{
    value:state, params:{
      countDown:countDown,      
    }
  }"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="countDown" (ngModelChange)="change()"/>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .needed-styles {
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-play-state: running;
          animation-timeline: auto;
          animation-range-start: normal;
          animation-range-end: normal;
      }
  `,
  ],
})
export class App {
  state = 'executed';
  countDown = 3;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state = 'neutral';
    });
  }

  change() {
    this.state = 'executed';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state = 'neutral';
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});

Stackblitz Demo

This is my solution using angular animations, we can pass the input to angular animation the variable that holds the countdown duration inside the params property, Then I apply all the other static styles using a class and the dynamic property can be assigned using {{countDown}}s, by setting the transition for :increment and :decrement we can restart the animation!
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  animate,
  keyframes,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';

const stylesArr = [
  style({ transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0 }),
  animate(
    '{{countDown}}s',
    keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0 }),
      style({ transform: 'scale(0.5)', offset: 1 }),
    ])
  ),
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgStyle, FormsModule],
  animations: [
    trigger('animate', [
      transition('* => *', stylesArr),
      transition(':increment', stylesArr),
      transition(':decrement', stylesArr),
    ]),
  ],
  template: `
    <div id="countdown">
      <div id="countdown-number">{{ countDown }}</div>
      <svg>
        <circle #circle r="18" cx="20" cy="20" class="needed-styles" [@animate]="{
    value:countDown, params:{
      countDown:countDown,      
    }
  }"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="countDown"/>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .needed-styles {
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-play-state: running;
          animation-timeline: auto;
          animation-range-start: normal;
          animation-range-end: normal;
      }
  `,
  ],
})
export class App {
  animationToggle = false;
  countDown = 3;
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for your prompt answer. I will give it a try, but I wanted to avoid to use the build-in angular animaton feature for this simple task.
